# In scala, why doesn't list.flatMap(List) work?

Tags: scala, functional-programming, monads

This works well

```
val l = List(1,2,3)
l.flatMap(x => List(x))
```

But this doesn't work:

```
l.flatMap(List)
```

And this doesn't work either:

```
l.flatmap(List.apply _)
```

Does anyone have ideas about this? Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For `List[A]`, `flatMap` expects a function from `A => GenTraversableOnce[B]`. The problem with using `List.apply` in that particular syntax is that `apply` allows repeated parameters `A*`, which is syntactic sugar for `Seq[A]`. So `List.apply` is really a `Seq[A] => List[A]`, which is not the same as `A => List[A]`. And we can see that in the error message:

```
scala> l.flatMap(List.apply)
<console>:9: error: polymorphic expression cannot be instantiated to expected type;
 found   : [A]Seq[A] => List[A]
 required: Int => scala.collection.GenTraversableOnce[?]
              l.flatMap(List.apply)
```

What you can do is make it clear that you are only using one parameter:

```
scala> l.flatMap(List(_))
res5: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3)

scala> l.flatMap(List.apply(_))
res6: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3)
```

And `l.flatMap(List)` could never work, because `List` is a class, and Scala will not treat it with the `apply` sugar to produce `l.flatMap(List.apply)`.

Comment: In the first example that works , can you explain why using a parenthesis makes it clear to Scala that the function expects single argument vs using not using parenthesis. `l flatMap List(_)` doesn't work for the reasons you gave, but magic does the parenthesis do.

Comment: Also the same parenthesis that you said works , doesn't work when you do  `l.flatMap(List(_*2))`

Answer (score 3):

This is because [`List.apply`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.6/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.List$@apply[A](xs:A*):List[A]) uses varargs:

```
def apply[A](xs: A*): List[A]
```

You are looking for a method that turns a single item into a list containing only that item. There is no special method just for that on the [`List`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.6/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.List$) object. Instead, they provide a more general method that takes any number of arguments, allowing your first statement (`List(1, 2, 3)`) to work.

You need to provide parentheses to create a `List` of only one object, thus you need to do the same when referring to the `apply` method using a `_` wildcard:

```
val listOfOne = List(1)

l.flatMap(List(_))
l.flatMap(List.apply(_))
```